# How do I run apps without Google Play Services?

Tags: applications, google-play-services

> "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services"

I know a lot of users managed to even uninstall Google services already, but I'm wondering how are they able to run the apps independently? I'm sure I'm missing something.
When I update Google Play services my phone becomes super slow and laggy.

Comment: They probably won't use that app, or use something like nogapps

Comment: actually most apps cant run unless i update G services i dont want to update it i might as well uninstall it

Comment: with a rooted device xprivacy or luckypatcher might work. beware the latter has some not-so-legal features though...